# How to substitute in sympy with Function.diff()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I have this code:

```
import sympy as *
from sympy.abc import t

init_printing(pretty_print=False)
theta = Function('theta')(t)
A = Matrix([theta, 1, cos(theta)])
A.diff().subs([(theta, 1), (theta.diff(), 2)])
```

I expected the output to be

```
>>> Matrix([
[        2],
[        0],
[-sin(1/2)]])
```

Instead, it was

```
>>> Matrix([
[            Derivative(1, t)],
[                           0],
[-sin(1/2)*Derivative(1, t)/2]])
```

However, the output indicated that `Derivative(theta, t)` was replaced with `Derivative(1, t)`, which is very strange. What more interesting is that if I replace the last line with `A.diff().subs(theta.diff(), 2).subs(theta, 1)`, the output is correct. The substitution has to be in this order to get the desired output. Why I could not use the initial approach and is there any better workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitutions are order specific. In the current development version of SymPy if you pass a set of replacements instead of a list it will (usually) work out the correct order so the more complicated patterns are done first: `.subs({(theta, 1), (theta.diff(), 2)})`. But you can always control the order by passing a list.

In the list you passed, you said to replace theta with 1 so `Derivative(theta,t)` became `Derivative(1, t)` and then there was nothing for `theta.diff()` to match since there were no longer any thetas.